# Yesod - how to make addScriptRemote add the script in the head section?

Tags: haskell, yesod, script-tag, yesod-forms

In Yesod/Haskell, I'd like to call addScriptRemote and have it add the `<script>` tag in the head section. As is, it seems to add the script only to the body section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where scripts get placed will depend on [jsLoader](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-2.9/yesod-core-1.4.9.1/Yesod-Core.html#v:jsLoader). If you want to make a change for a specific script, you can use `toWidgetHead [hamlet|<script src=...">|]`.

Comment: Can I change the `jsLoader`?

Comment: Yes, when declaring your Yesod instance